# Labels in feynman diagrams using feynmf

Tags: feynmf

I'm getting familiar with drawing feynman diagrams using `feynmf` package and I
was trying to draw this process. However, labels do not display in the diagrams. Is there any error? Please, let me know if there's one.

```
\begin{fmffile}{mu}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item $\mu \rightarrow e\gamma$ (SM) \hfill\\
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(60,35)
    \fmfleftn{i}{2}
    \fmfrightn{o}{2}
    \fmf{plain,label=$\mu$}{i1,v1,v3,o1}
    \fmffreeze
    \fmf{phantom}{i2,v4,o2}
    \fmffreeze
    \fmf{zigzag,left=0.6,label=$W^+$,label.side=left}{v1,v2}
    \fmf{zigzag,left=0.6}{v2,v3}
    \fmf{photon,tension=1.5,label=$\gamma$}{v2,v4}
    \fmfdotn{v}{3}
    \end{fmfgraph*}
    \item $\mu \rightarrow e\gamma$ (MSSM) \hfill\\
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(60,35)
    \fmfleftn{i}{2}
    \fmfrightn{o}{2}
    \fmf{fermion,label=$\mu$}{i1,v1,v3,o1}
    \fmffreeze
    \fmf{phantom}{i2,v4,o2}
    \fmffreeze
    \fmf{dashes,left=0.6,label=$W^+$,label.side=left}{v1,v2}
    \fmf{dashes,left=0.6}{v2,v3}
    \fmf{photon,tension=1.5,label=$\gamma$}{v2,v4}
    \fmfdotn{v}{3}
    \end{fmfgraph*}
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(60,35)
    \fmfleftn{i}{2}
    \fmfrightn{o}{2}
    \fmf{phantom,label=$\mu$}{i1,v1,v3,o1}
    \fmffreeze
    \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1}
    \fmf{dashes}{v1,v3}
    \fmf{fermion}{v3,o1}
    \fmf{phantom}{i2,v4,o2}
    \fmffreeze
    \fmf{plain,left=0.6,label=$W^+$,label.side=left}{v1,v2}
    \fmf{plain,left=0.6}{v2,v3}
    \fmf{photon,tension=1.5,label=$\gamma$}{v2,v4}
    \fmfdotn{v}{3}
    \end{fmfgraph*}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{fmffile}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! This is what I get with your code: http://i.imgur.com/ldqu5Ct.png using `\usepackage{feynmp-auto}`. Do you get something different?

Comment: When I use `feynmp-auto` the diagrams do not display at all :/ Do I need to install something?

Comment: Weird. No, there should be no need for nothing else. Try a simple experiment; copy paste this code exactly as is: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}

\begin{document}

\begin{fmffile}{mu}
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(60,35)
    \fmfleftn{i}{2}
    \fmfrightn{o}{2}
    \fmf{plain,label=$\mu$}{i1,v1,v3,o1}
    \fmffreeze
    \fmf{phantom}{i2,v4,o2}
    \fmffreeze
    \fmf{zigzag,left=0.6,label=$W^+$,label.side=left}{v1,v2}
    \fmf{zigzag,left=0.6}{v2,v3}
    \fmf{photon,tension=1.5,label=$\gamma$}{v2,v4}
    \fmfdotn{v}{3}
    \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}

\end{document}`

Comment: And compile it. What do you get?

Comment: Same result, the diagram does not display in the pdf.

Comment: What do you get in the `.log` file in the *File List* section when you run this: `\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}

\begin{document}

\begin{fmffile}{mu}
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(60,35)
    \fmfleftn{i}{2}
    \fmfrightn{o}{2}
    \fmf{plain,label=$\mu$}{i1,v1,v3,o1}
    \fmffreeze
    \fmf{phantom}{i2,v4,o2}
    \fmffreeze
    \fmf{zigzag,left=0.6,label=$W^+$,label.side=left}{v1,v2}
    \fmf{zigzag,left=0.6}{v2,v3}
    \fmf{photon,tension=1.5,label=$\gamma$}{v2,v4}
    \fmfdotn{v}{3}
    \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}

\end{document}`

Comment: Do you mean this? *File List*
 article.cls size10.clo   
feynmp-auto.sty    
  feynmp.sty    
graphics.sty    
    trig.sty    
graphics.cfg    
  pdftex.def    
infwarerr.sty    
 ltxcmds.sty    
   ifpdf.sty    
 ifxetex.sty    
pdftexcmds.sty    
ifluatex.sty    
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    
  grfext.sty    
kvdefinekeys.sty    
kvoptions.sty    
  keyval.sty    
kvsetkeys.sty    
etexcmds.sty    
epstopdf-sys.cfg

Comment: Yes, that, but the important information is missing. I want to see the version of the packages.

Comment: *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
feynmp-auto.sty    2013/05/03 v1.1 Automatic processing of feynmp graphics
  feynmp.sty    1996/12/02 v1.08 LaTeX/MetaPost Feynman Diagram Package (ohl)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX

Comment: infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
supp-pdf.mkii

Comment: epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live

Comment: I see that some of your packages are outdated, but I did some tests using older versions of TeX Live (down to 2013) and no problems here. Which LaTeX system (MiKTeX, TeX Live) do you use (and which version)?